# How can I tell, in hook_form_alter(), if a node form is for the node in its default language or a translation?

Tags: forms, i18n-l10n

I'm implementing [hook_form_BASE_FORM_ID_alter()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Form%21form.api.php/function/hook_form_BASE_FORM_ID_alter/9.2.x) in a custom module. I'd like to know if my form is for the node in its default language, or a translation of that original node.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like I can get it from the form's object, i.e. the form's node, and then use the node's [isDefaultTranslation()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21ContentEntityBase.php/function/ContentEntityBase%3A%3AisDefaultTranslation/9.2.x) method.

For example:

```
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;

function MY_MODULE_form_node_form_alter(&$form, FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {
  /** @var \Drupal\node\NodeInterface $node */
  $node = $form_state->getFormObject()->getEntity();
  if ($node->isDefaultTranslation()) {
    // The node form is for the node in its default language.
  }
  else {
    // The node form is for a translation of the node.
  }
}
```